# DateTimeFormatterBuilder with default zone id?

Tags: java, java-time, date-parsing, jsr310

I have a requirement where if ISO date time does not specify zone offset, I should assume Europe/Bratislava's current offset.

Basically `"2020-03-26T22:47:32.497" -> "2020-03-26T22:47:32.497+01:00"`

Tldr; do parse time zone id if there is one, **but default to a specific one if none is present**

What I have now

```
private val isoDateTimeParser = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField...?)
    .toFormatter()
```

Obviously it doesnt work. Is it even possible? Should I just have 2 formatters (one with tz, one without) and try one after another?

Answer (score 1):

Add an "override zone" to the formatter with [`withZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone-java.time.ZoneId-)

```
private val isoDateTimeParser = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
    .toFormatter()
    .withZone(/*whatever*/)
```

From the docs

> If a zone has been parsed directly from the text, perhaps because
>   DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendZoneId() was used, then this override
>   zone has no effect

---

By the way, there is very rarely any reason for a formatter to be an instance variable. It should be static. Given that it's immutable, and therefore a constant, it should be upper case as well.

```
private static final ISO_DATE_TIME_PARSER = ...
```

Comment: doesnt work. `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-03-26T22:47:32.497' could not be parsed at index 23`

Comment: @urSus ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME does not have an optional offset, it is mandatory.

Comment: well thats my whole question, how to attach a default to optional timezone

Comment: @urSus See the edit friend